# Por qué cambian los valores en los campos muchas veces si los estoy "limpiando" con JQuery(Javascript) (setearlos en " ")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación en `ASP .Net MVC 5`. Ya he completado toda mi vista, excepto que no sé como reparar este error. Agrego un producto, le ingreso la cantidad y se visualiza en el detalle correctamente; el problema se presenta cuando agrego los demás productos. Es más,cuando le doy en "AGREGAR" deberían limpiarse porque esos campos los he seteado en " " en la función limpiar (hecha con javascript). He probado poniéndole:

```
$("#txtnombreproducto").val(null); 
$("#txtnombreproducto").val("");
$("#txtnombreproducto").val('');
```

y nada aún. Lo que más me intriga es que cómo rayos cuando selecciono el siguiente producto, los `input` parpadean y en poco segundos cambian su valor entre el producto seleccionado anterior y el actual. Cuando le ingreso la cantidad y le doy en "AGREGAR" es como si se agregara en el detalle el producto del segundo actual que se encuentra en el `input` como se muestra en la imágen.

[Imágen del problema > .GIF](https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-547eb2e9e2.gif)

```js
 //variables
    var total = 0;
    var valor = 0;
    var subtotal = 0;
    var pagar = 0;

    function obtenerCliente(Cliente) {

        var watchclose = setInterval(function () {
            $("#txtruc").val(Cliente.Ruc);
            $("#txtnombre").val(Cliente.Nombre);
            $("#txtdireccion").val(Cliente.Direccion);

        });
    }

    function obtenerProducto(Producto) {

        var watchclose = setInterval(function () {
            $("#txtcodigoproducto").val(Producto.Codigo);
            $("#txtnombreproducto").val(Producto.Nombre);
            $("#txtprecio").val(Producto.Precio);

        });
    }

    function fn_agregar() {
...
```

Aquí está el código de la vista, en él está tanto el javascript como el html:

```js
<script>
function fn_agregar() {

  cadena = "<tr>"
  cadena = cadena + "<td>" + $("#txtcodigoproducto").val() + "</td>";
  cadena = cadena + "<td>" + $("#txtnombreproducto").val() + "</td>";
  cadena = cadena + "<td>" + $("#cantidad").val() + "</td>";
  cadena = cadena + "<td>" + $("#txtprecio").val() + "</td>";
  //cadena = cadena + "<td>" + $("#descuento").val() + "</td>";

  var y = 0;
  var x = 0;
  //var des = 0;
  y = $("#cantidad").val();
  x = $("#txtprecio").val();
  //des = $("#descuento").val();
  subtotal = (x * y);



  cadena = cadena + "<td>" + subtotal.toFixed(2) + "</td>"
  cadena = cadena + "<td><a class ='elimina'><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span></button></a></td>";
  $("#detalle tbody").append(cadena);

  sumar();

  //sumarpagar();

  fn_dar_eliminar();

  //$("#cantidad").val(' ');
  limpiarCliente();
  limpiar();
};


function limpiar() {
  $("#txtnombreproducto").val("");
  $("#txtcodigoproducto").val("");
  $("#txtprecio").val("");
  //$("#ListaProducto").val("");
  $("#cantidad").val("");
  //$("#Pagar").val("");
}

function limpiarCliente() {
  $("tbody tr #txtnombre").val('');
  $("tbody tr #txtdireccion").val('');
  $("tbody tr #txtruc").val('');
}

function limpiarDetalle() {
  $("#detalle tbody tr").val("");
  ("#Pagar").val(pagar);
}

function sumar() {
  total = total + subtotal;
  console.info(total);
  $("#TotalaPagar").val(total.toFixed(2));

  pagar = total + 0.18 * total;
  console.info(pagar);
  $("#Pagar").val(pagar.toFixed(2));
}

//function sumarpagar() {
//    pagar = total + 0.18*total;
//    console.info(pagar);
//    $("#Pagar").val(pagar);

//}

function restar() {
  total = total - valor;
  $("#TotalaPagar").val(total.toFixed(2));

  pagar = pagar - valor;
  $("#Pagar").val(pagar.toFixed(2));

}

function fn_dar_eliminar() {
  $("a.elimina").click(function() {
    valor = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(4).html();

    $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut("normal", function() {
      $(this).remove();
      restar();
    });
  });
};

</script>
```

```
<form action="javascript:fn_agregar()" ; method="post" id="frm_usu">

<table class="table">

    <tr style="font-size:20px;">

        <td>
            Producto <input style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700;" class="form-control" type="text" id="txtnombreproducto" readonly required />
        </td>

        <td>
            Id <input style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700;" type="text" id="txtcodigoproducto" class="form-control" readonly required />
        </td>

        <td>
            Precio <input style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700;" type="text" id="txtprecio" class="form-control" readonly required />
        </td>

        <td>
            Cantidad <input style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700;" class="form-control" type="text" id="cantidad" value="Ingrese Cantidad" onfocus="this.value = '';" required />
        </td>

        <td>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">

                <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:29px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnproductos" id="btnproductos">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código que usas para seleccionar poner los datos desde el modal a la ventana principal

Comment: no entiendo :/.

Comment: El codigo que hace que el producto seleccionado en la ventana Obtener Producto, se muestre en la ventana donde indicas la cantidad

Comment: Entiendo,listo!

Comment: ¿Conoces cómo funciona un "setInterval"?

Comment: no mucho,solo supongo que setea cada rango de tiempo, verdad? es eso lo que debería cambiar?

Comment: Si, quita el setInterval

Comment: deberias usar esta https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: probé esa funcióm y salió como yo quería,muchad gracias